# How to get minimum value of a group?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, minimum

I need to get the Comment of the Quotation which have the minimum lineTotal of each project(PrjCode). How to get it
Following query i have tried and but it didn't worked

```
  select distinct a.PrjCode,b.LineTotal as 'Neg.rate',(case when min(b.LineTotal) = b.LineTotal then c.Comments end)
from OPRJ a
Left Join PQT1 b on b.Project = a.PrjCode
Inner Join OPQT c on c.DocEntry = b.DocEntry
Group by a.PrjCode,a.PrjName,b.LineTotal,c.Comments
having min(b.LineTotal) = b.LineTotal
Order by a.PrjCode
```

Output as follows

[image]

expected output as follows

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show the sample data as well as the desired results.  A db fiddle of some sort is also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `distinct` when you have used `group by` though sample data not available just assume below may work for you

```
select  a.PrjCode,b.LineTotal as 'Neg.rate',
min(c.Comments )
from OPRJ a
Left Join PQT1 b on b.Project = a.PrjCode
Inner Join OPQT c on c.DocEntry = b.DocEntry
Group by a.PrjCode,a.PrjName,b.LineTotal    
Order by a.PrjCode
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
     SELECT c.PrjCode, b.LineTotal AS 'Neg.rate', e.Comments FROM ( 
     (SELECT a.PrjCode, MIN(b.LineTotal) AS LineTotal FROM OPRJ a
     LEFT JOIN PQT1 b ON b.Project = a.PrjCode GROUP BY a.PrjCode)c
     INNER JOIN  PQT1 d ON d.Project = c.PrjCode AND d.LineTotal = c.LineTotal
     INNER JOIN  OPQT e ON e.DocEntry = d.DocEntry ORDER BY c.PrjCode)f;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select  a.PrjCode,b.LineTotal as 'Neg.rate', c.Comments
from OPRJ a
Left Join PQT1 b on b.Project = a.PrjCode
Inner Join OPQT c on c.DocEntry = b.DocEntry
Group by a.PrjCode
Order by b.LineTotal, a.PrjCode
```